# Does "if $a \mid b$ and $c \equiv c' \mod b,$ then $c \equiv c' \mod a$" admit any interesting generalizations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

Recall that divisibility of integers is transitive, meaning:

**Proposition 0.** If $a \mid b$ and $b \mid c$, then $a \mid c$.

This can be generalized slightly by involving modular arithmetic:

**Proposition 1.** If $a \mid b$ and $c \equiv c' \mod b,$ then $c \equiv c' \mod a.$

Proposition 0 is obtained in the case $c' = 0$.

> **Question.** Are there any further generalizations of this where e.g. $a \mid b$ is replaced by a more general condition and the necessary changes are made to the conclusion?

Comment: *Proposition 1* is essentially *proposition 0* applied to $c-c^{'}$. So, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of Proposition 0, as I read it, is just an associativity of products:
$$
m_1(m_2m_3)=m_1m_2m_3=(m_1m_2)m_3
$$
for integers $m_1,m_2,m_3$. Indeed: with $m_1=c/b$, $m_2=b/a$, and $m_3=a$, we have:
$$
c=\frac{c}{b}\left(\frac{b}{a}a\right)=\left(\frac{c}{b}\frac{b}{a}\right)a
$$
giving Proposition 0. Letting $m_1=(c-c')/b$ gives Proposition 1. So you can generalize in a few ways:
$$
m_1(m_2\ldots m_N)=(m_1\ldots m_{N-1})m_N
$$
yielding for example
$$
d_N=\frac{d_N}{d_{N-1}}\left[\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N-2}\frac{d_{i+1}}{d_i}\right)\cdot d_1\right]=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{N-1}\frac{d_{i+1}}{d_i}\right]d_1.
$$
And you can replace $d_i$ with $d_i-d_i'$ of course for some or all of the $i$'s.